# google places JS API localized place type

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a project using the google maps JS API. i would like to display the place type in a similar fashion to how a google search would result (example below).

[image]
[image]

Using the getDetails method in PlacesService ([as show here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details)), i can receive an array of types for a place, yet they are not descriptive as what a google search shows, and are not localized. is it possible to achieve using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the API doesn't provide this information.

There are a couple of feature requests in the Google issue tracker that might match your requirement:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822953

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827225

You can star these feature requests to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.